# how to bind two models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

please help a beginner. I'm trying to build a poll app in Django and I want to change my admin panel so that I can change and add questions and choices in the same page iv already tried to create a new model and bind the question and choice model together but didn't work please help me.
this is my models.py inside my poll app and another problem I have is that I want to have different numbers of choices for different questions  but I don't know how to write

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
class Bind(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')    
    add_question =Question(question_text=question_text,pub_date=pub_date)

    choice_text_1= models.CharField(max_length=200,default='yes')
    votes_1= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    choice_text_2= models.CharField(max_length=200,default='yes')
    votes_2= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    choice_text_3= models.CharField(max_length=200,default='yes')
    votes_3= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    choice_text_4= models.CharField(max_length=200,default='yes')
    votes_4= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    add_choice1=Choice(choice_text=choice_text_1,votes=votes_1)
    add_choice2=Choice(choice_text=choice_text_2,votes=votes_2)
    add_choice3=Choice(choice_text=choice_text_3,votes=votes_3)
    add_choice4=Choice(choice_text=choice_text_4,votes=votes_4)
    def __str__(self):

        return self.question_text 
        return self.choice_text
```

and this is my admin panel id like to change it that I can add question with different number of choices and when I save I can find save question in question model pannel and choices in the choice model panel please help me I'm a beginner
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rd8R.png)

and this is views.py file:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
  template_name = 'polls/index.html'
  context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
  def get_queryset(self):
    return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
  model = Question
  template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
  model = Question
  template_name = 'polls/results.html'
def vote(request, question_id):
 question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
 try:
  selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
 except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):

  return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question,'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",})
 else:
  selected_choice.votes += 1
  selected_choice.save()

  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

and the error by executing the python manage.py migrate

> C:\projects\AM\FM\mysite>python manage.py migrate Operations to
> perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, polls,
> sessions Running migrations:   Applying
> polls.0009_auto_20200914_1002...Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init*_.py",
> line 1774, in get_prep_value
> return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'choice'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in
>
> main()   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py",
> line 401, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py",
> line 395, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 330, in run_from_argv
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 371, in execute
> output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 85, in wrapped
> res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
> line 243, in handle
> post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 117, in migrate
> state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
> state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 227, in apply_migration
> state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
> line 124, in apply
> operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
> "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py",
> line 104, in database_forwards
> schema_editor.add_field(   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> line 328, in add_field
> self.*remake_table(model, create_field=field)   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> line 189, in *remake_table
> self.effective_default(create_field)   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
> line 303, in effective_default
> return field.get_db_prep_save(self.*effective_default(field), self.connection)   File
> "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py",
> line 971, in get_db_prep_save
> return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)   File
> "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init**.py",
> line 823, in get_db_prep_save
> return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)   File
> "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init**.py",
> line 2388, in get_db_prep_value
> value = self.get_prep_value(value)   File "C:\projects\AM\FM\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init**.py",
> line 1776, in get_prep_value
> raise e.**class**( ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'choice'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly assign other models to other model's fields. You have to use either `ForeignKey` (One Object To Many Referrable Objects) or `ManyToManyField` (Many Objects Can Be Contained To This Object).

At this point, you might want to consider making `class Bind` to `class Questionnaire` since you're combining them.

With that, with fixes applied and redundancies, this should be the final code (for inheritances only!)

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question_choices = models.ForeignKey("Choice", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(help_text='date published', auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

# No need to refer to the `Question` Model unless you have something to do important.
# Cross-Reference is okay, but its redundant unless special handling is required (for instance, you want pure integrity of ownership of this object, etc. But its quite hard to manage if your models were scaling.)
class Choice(models.Model):
    # question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    questions = models.ManyToManyField("Question", blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(help_text='date published', auto_now_add=True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

NOTES:

1. If you read the changes closely, you might see yourself, why I assigned the object in "str" form? That's because Django was able to load objects, even or after the one who requires it. Meaning, You don't need to put another object on the top to refer at, but rather, just put it in `str` reference even the object is placed anywhere and you're good to go.
2. Note that in `DateTimeField`, you would want to consider `auto_now_add=True`, it automatically handles the time where this object has been saved for the first time.
3. I want to make all choices under Question. This would be nice because if you want to make a question, there's a field available for you to create a choice to.
4. I changed `Bind` with `Questionnaire` for clarity. This should be enough to see the relationship or inheritance to your model.
5. I used `ManyToManyField` to set number of questions (or objects) to this `Questionnaire`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help h don't know why but I get this error ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'choice'. is this because of views.py ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess provide a traceback in your question so that we could figure it out more.

Comment: Hey, you have an error in your `views.py` which is this query `selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])`. I'm not sure what would be the value of `request.POST` but I assure its not the key of the question that is being referred at which emits an error.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and attention but I can't handle this error i deleted the Questioner class but i keep getting this error i don't know what should i do please help me .

Comment: thank you very much it worked .thank you again for your time and attention

Comment: No problem. Sorry I was unable to get back to you on your recent reply. Glad it went okay.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in such cases, you don't need to create "Bind" model. You just need to add "sequence" integer field into your Choice model. Then, each question can have infinite number of choices, for example:

```
Choice.objects.create(question=question1, sequence=0)
Choice.objects.create(question=question1, sequence=1)
Choice.objects.create(question=question1, sequence=2)...
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and attention . can you please help me with this new problem I have when I execute python manage.py migrate I get this error ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'choice'